# Ember: Disable SRI on a single file

Tags: ember.js

How can disable sub resource integrity for a specific file in a Ember.js application? I tried putting this but no luck

```
"SRI": {
    exclude: ['assets/env.js']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Why do you need to exclude a specific file from being protected by SRI? This opens up a risk which should be protected against by SRI. So you should do this with care and only if there isn't any other chance to do what you habe to do.

SRI is handled by [`ember-cli-sri`](https://github.com/jonathanKingston/ember-cli-sri). It doesn't have an `exclude` option. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/jonathanKingston/ember-cli-sri/issues/28) requesting such a feature.

In the mentioned issue some recommends to use the fail safe behavior as a work-a-round. ember-cli-sri should fail safe if having wrong configuration:

> This addon should fail safely at all times so resources matching
>   https? need:
>
> - Asset URL needs to start with fingerprint.prepend
> - Asset must use fingerprinting with md5
> - Asset must match md5 sum to what is in the filesystem
> - An SRI.crossorigin attribute must be set or a matching origin to fingerprint.prepend
>
> If the config is not set correctly it should result in just a lack of SRI protection, which is better than a broken website.
>
> Please file bugs if you find a case when the config doesn't 'fail
>   safe', is not clear or results in a broken page.

Someone recommends to disable SRI per file by excluding the file from being fingerprinted. I would not recommend that one. Fingerprinting helps you prevent caching issues. You will likely face strange issues even on production deployments if disabling it even for only one file.

It might be safer to disable SRI for at least the full domain by setting a wrong crossorigin or disabling altogether. It could be disabled using `enabled` option or by uninstalling `ember-cli-sri` package.

If you have the time and knowledge implementing the missing exclude feature and providing it as a PR to the community would be the best solution of course. :-)

Comment: The reason I am doing this, is because we are putting our ember application in a docker image so it will build only one time and this file contains environment variables that updated by running  shell script in different docker environment

Comment: do you bundle a webservice in the docker container? have you considered to just get the config with AJAX as a JSON instead of a `js` file?

Comment: My image contains ember app and nginx server. The might be better ways to do this I am just starting on docker. The AJAx call would get the config from where?